# why does tkinter does not recognise entry values?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6, tkinter-entry

first my specs:
python 3.6.1
windows 10
Well, i can´t figure out why these code gives me these error:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Juan Diego\Desktop\cosasque no son programas (miosno)\Test1 - copia.py", line 11, in run1
    num= int(num_Entry.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

I understand that python does not recognize `num_Entry` as an Entry, but WHY?

```
import tkinter
        import fractions
        #declares the function
        main= tkinter.Tk(className="main")
        num_Entry =tkinter.Entry(main).pack()
        den_Entry = tkinter.Entry(main).pack()
        def run1():
            global den_Entry
            global num_Entry
            num= int(num_Entry.get())
            den= int(den_Entry.get())
            den=int(input("denominator 1\n:-:->"))
            Fraction1= fractions.Fraction(num,den)
            print(Fraction1)
        #runs the code
        button = tkinter.Button(main, text="run!",command= run1).pack()
        main.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a widget and layout on the same line. You need to split them all into 2 lines like this:

```
den_Entry = tkinter.Entry(main)
den_Entry.pack()
```